# Multiple Hutcheson t-test in Package: ecolTest

Tags: t-test

I am trying to run this example code on my own df:

```
data("polychaeta_abundance")
multiple_Hutcheson_t_test(x = polychaeta_abundance,
                          shannon.base = 10)
```

However I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in multiple_Hutcheson_t_test(x = Fish_Shannon_long, shannon.base = 10) : 
  x must be numeric
```

If I have understood it correctly, x is any df that has the correct format. I followed the instructions in reshaping my df into the correct format (Columns must correspond to the samples and rows to species). This did not help.

Comment: Oh, and when running the example code, it works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. I still had a column that was not numeric. It was the column with fish names. When removing it everything worked.

That column is not necessary for the calculations.